# How to mock android context using mockk library

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-resources, mockk

I am new in JUnit testing on Android and I'm testing a function, which is using android context object to get a string resources and making some comparsions. How can I mock android context object to successfully test this function? For testing I'm using Mockk testing library.

```
  private val context = mockk<Context>()
  private val contextWrapper = ApplicationContextWrapper(context)
  private val objectUnderTest = AppLinkService(contextWrapper)
```

I was trying to mock context using `mockk<Context>()`, but I'm getting the following exception

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: Context(#1).getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Using relaxed mock solved my problem

```
val mContextMock = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it would be risky to mock a context as it provides information about the application environment and does a lot under the hood.

[ApplicationProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider) provides the ability to retrieve the current application Context in tests.
All you need to do is import [the latest version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test) of the `androidx:test:core` library

```
dependencies {
    // To use the androidx.test.core APIs
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.5.0")
    ...
}
```

And then retrieve the context in your test class

```
private val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```